# How to query by date on cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to query some data that is between two dates, but nothing seems to work. These are my dates, I saw on a post that the division by 1000 should work , but it's not. Ive tried firebase.firestore but says firebase it's not defined but I don't know how to simply reference to firebase.firestore.Timestamp

```js
let now = new Date()
  let yesterday = Math.round((new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - 1).getTime())/1000)
  now = Math.round(now.getTime()/1000)
```

This is my query attempt. Nothing works and it just returns my empty array because the query has no data to iterate through the forEach.

```js
let snapshot = await db.collection('appointments')
  .where('status', '==', 'Pending')
  .where('startDate', '<=', now)
  .where('startDate', '>', yesterday)
  .get().then(docs => {
    docs.forEach(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.id, '=>', snapshot.data());
      console.log(snapshot.data()['doctor']);
      doctor_mail.push(snapshot.id)
      doctor_mail.push(snapshot.data())
    });
    return doctor_mail
  }).
  catch(err => {
    return res.send(err)
  });
  console.log(doctor_mail)
  res.send(snapshot)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the corresponding index in Firestore? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I don't get any error messages, just nothing comes back from the query. And the index is good 'startDate' actually exists

Answer (score 1):

The query is not returning anything because there is nothing to return. If you are querying for a string representing a date and the data is a timestamp in the Firestore, so in order to know that, it would be need to check a sample document to compare, since in the first part of your question you mentioned that you want to get a Firestore timestamp, you can do it with this code:

```
const timestamp = db.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
//if you want it as a date object
const date = timestamp.toDate();
```

As per what you asked in the comments, for getting the value of Today and Yesterday in Timestamp you can do the following:

```
var todayTimestamp = timestamp.now();
var date = new Date().setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
var yesterdayTimestamp = timestamp.fromDate(date);
```

And convert them back to date so you can operate them if needed, you can check more details on the Timestamp in this [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)

Comment: I have my index already created, there is no problem with that at all. But in the code you wrote, how do I specify the date from today and yesterday using timestamp.toDate() ?

Comment: for today you can do `timestamp.now( )`, for yesterday you could do `var date = new Date().setDate(date.getDate() - 1); timestamp.fromDate(date);` I will edit that into the answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the thing here was that I was wrongly calling db as const db = firebase.firestore.

Instead I just had to go for:

```js
const db = admin.firestore()
```